# Hive percentile_approx function is broken, isn't it?

Tags: hadoop

- I am using Hive 1.2.1000.2.4.2.0-258.
- There are 4850000+ rows in the table, 14511 rows of A between 73 and 74, and 3 cols-  group_id,  A  and B.
- Group_id is actually equal to 0.
- Almost all of A and B are integers.

I was using the following scripts to find statistic summaries from a table:

```
select group_id, --group_id=0 a constant
  percentile_approx(A , 0.5) as A_mdn, 
  percentile_approx(A , 0.25) as A_Q1, 
  percentile_approx(A , 0.75) as A_Q3, 
  percentile_approx(A , array(0.2,0.15, 0.1,0.05,0.025,0.001)) as A_i, 
  min(A) as min_A,
  percentile_approx(B , 0.5) as B_mdn, 
  percentile_approx(B , 0.25) as B_Q1, 
  percentile_approx(B , 0.75) as B_Q3, 
  percentile_approx(B , array(0.8,0.85, 0.9, 0.95,0.975)) as B_i
  from table
  group by group_id;
```

The result I got is:

```
0   
73.21058033222496   
73.21058033222496   
462.16968382794516
[73.21058033222496,73.21058033222496,73.21058033222496,73.21058033222496,73.21058033222496,73.21058033222496]   
0.0 
1.0 
1.0 
2.0  
[2.0,3.0,4.0,8.11278644563614,17.0]
```

Then I change the code as following:

```
select group_id, --group_id=0 a constant
  percentile(cast(A as bigint), 0.5) as A_mdn, 
  percentile(cast(A as bigint), 0.25) as A_Q1, 
  percentile(cast(A as bigint), 0.75) as A_Q3, 
  percentile(cast(A as bigint), array(0.2,0.15, 0.1,0.05,0.025,0.001)) as A_i, 
  min(A) as min_A,
  percentile(cast(B as bigint), 0.5) as B_mdn, 
  percentile(cast(B as bigint), 0.25) as B_Q1, 
  percentile(cast(B as bigint), 0.75) as B_Q3, 
  percentile(cast(B as bigint), array(0.8,0.85, 0.9, 0.95,0.975)) as B_i
  from table
  group by group_id
```

The new result is:

```
 0  
72.0    
6.0 
762.0    
[3.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
0.0
1.0 
1.0 
2.0  
[2.0,3.0,4.0,9.0,17.0]
```

To double check the truth, I also load this table to R. Following is the R-result:

```
A:
Min 0
Q1: 6
Median: 72
Q3: 762
0.2 quantile:  3
0.15 quantile: 1.5
0.1 quantile:  1
0.05 quantile: 0
0.025 quantile:0
0.001 quantile:0

B
Q1: 1
Median: 1
Q3: 2
0.8 quantile:  2    
0.85 quantile: 3
0.9 quantile:  4
0.95 quantile: 9
0.975 quantile:17
```

Obviously, R result is consistent with percentile function, but percentile_approx gives me the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the percentile_approx doesn't have any approximation guarantees, except when you set the `accuracy` to be greater than or equal to the # of data points.

The source for it is here: https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/NumericHistogram.java

From a quick reading, the gist is that it creates `accuracy` buckets, and then when it runs out of buckets it merges buckets by finding the two closest buckets and combining them with a weighted sum.

This will break with various inputs though. In particular, if you have datapoints that are very high/very low and are spaced far away from each other, it will break the algorithm. If you first clip your data to be in a range where there are not many outliers, it should perform better.

You might consider randomly sampling the data and computing non-approx percentile instead if your data is too skewed though.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns a true value if "all" the values are integers. You said that almost all of A and B are integers.

Try to cast the complete column A to int and see if you come close to the answer.

I don't think, you will ever get exactly the same answer as R because R's percentile function most likely takes non-integers also.

One way to get the exact answer would be to write your own UDF and use it instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My point is that result of percentile_approx is wrong, not even an "approx".

Comment: Try this: percentile_approx(A , 0.5, ) as A_mdn

Comment: Disregard the above comment. Try this : percentile_approx(A , 0.5, [,5000000] ) as A_mdn. The '5000000' parameter should be > number of distinct records in dataset. You said that you have 4.85m+ records so try running the above command and see if the results are closer.